# Running GUI app through Docker on a Mac

Tags: linux, docker, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run a GUI app inside of docker (using python and displaying matplotlib plots).

After searching around, it seems the way to start a docker container with X11 forwarding is with the following run commands:

```
IP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)

xhost + $IP

docker run --rm -it \
    --network=host \
    --hostname $(hostname) \
    -e DISPLAY=$IP:0 \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    --user root \
    docker_image \
    bash
```

This works, however, after about 10 mins I get the following error and any GUI application I have open, closes. After this, text is no longer rendered in the terminal, and if I press `enter` the PS1 prompt, `[ins] (DOCKER) RNNs $`, is just repeated on the same line:

```bsh
[ins] (DOCKER) RNNs $
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "192.168.105.55:0"
      after 2218 requests (2216 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
[ins] (DOCKER) RNNs $ [ins] (DOCKER) RNNs $ [ins] (DOCKER) RNNs $ [ins] (DOCKER) RNNs $
```

Does anyone know the cause/solution to this?

Linux distro: Ubuntu 18.04
Mac distor: OSX 10.14.2
Xquartz: 2.7.11

Comment: I am actually confused how this works at all: On Mac, you usually run docker on a virtual Linux machine (xhyve/bhyve etc.), and sharing the unix socket between this virtual machine and the host would only allow an X client inside the docker image to access the X server running inside the virtual machine. Have you tried X over network (set up docker image so it can reach Mac host), and have it connect to XQuartz?

Comment: No I don’t think I I have. Can you send me something that talkes about configuring that?

Comment: I actually have the same problem. Did @ben by any chance figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately. A crummy work-around was to keep a tmux window open in docker. When that error showed up, exit out of the tmux pane and start a new one. This made it so i didn't have to shut the container down, but still meant I had to exit out of my work

Comment: Try `xhost + 127.0.0.1` and `docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 --user root <image> bash` (as seen here: https://medium.com/@mreichelt/how-to-show-x11-windows-within-docker-on-mac-50759f4b65cb) This might have made it better... but I don't remember for sure.

Comment: I get the same error. Tried out what @Ben recommended, but still get crashes. `Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server host.docker.internal:0.`